# how to output from cfhttp

Tags: coldfusion

I have a page which tries to get the value from another server using cfhttp. Then using cfhttpparam to iterate through all form fields and then construct a struct. This struct will then be appended to an array using arrayAppend.
My query is, I want to see if all the form fields and values have been inserted into the struct. I tried to put cfoutput, but its not working inside cfhttp.
Could any one please help me out in this?
Many thanks in advance
This is the code snippet

```
<cfhttp url="#URL#" throwonerror="yes" method="post" timeout="300">
    <cfloop list="#listSort(structKeyList(form),'textnocase')#" index="i">
        <cfif i is not "fieldnames">
            <cfset arrayOfValues = listToArray(evaluate('form.#i#'),',') />

                <cfif arrayLen(arrayOfValues) LT 2>
                        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="#i#" value="#evaluate('form.#i#')#" />

                        <cfset tempStruct = structNew() />
                        <cfset tempStruct.name = i />
                        <cfset tempStruct.value = evaluate('form.#i#') />
                        <cfset tempStruct.from = 'form' />
                        <cfset arrayAppend(array1,tempStruct) />

                <cfelse>

                            <cfloop from="1"to="#arrayLen(arrayOfValues)#" index="j">
                                <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="#i#" value="#arrayOfValues[j]#" />

                                <cfset tempStruct = structNew() />
                                <cfset tempStruct.name = i />
                                <cfset tempStruct.value = arrayOfValues[j] />
                                <cfset tempStruct.from = 'form' />
                                <cfset arrayAppend(array1,tempStruct) />
                        </cfloop>

                </cfif>

        </cfif>
        </cfloop>
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using evaluate(). Instead, just reference form values as #form[i]#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your `<cfhttp>`

```
<cfdump var="#array1#">
```